# print the strings in ASCII collating sequence

Tags: c

I am studying C from Stephen Prata's *C Primer Plus*. Here is one question from chapter 11.

> Write a program that reads in up to 10 strings or to EOF, whichever comes
>   first. Have it offer the user a menu with five choices: print the original 
>   list of strings, print the strings in ASCII collating sequence, 
>   print the strings in order
>   of increasing length, print the strings in order of the length of the first word
>   in the string, and quit. Have the menu recycle until the user enters the quit
>   request. The program, of course, should actually perform the promised tasks

I understand the problem except for the bit where it asks "print the strings in ASCII collating sequence".  What does it mean?  Does it mean that I have to change the
order of characters as in ASCII collating sequence?

Comment: This means `compared lexicographically` sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collation means the "logical" ordering of strings. For the "C" locale, this is indeed equivalent to sorting by ASCII codes (using `strcmp()`).

**However**, collation is **locale-dependent**.

For example, in ISO 8859-1 encoding and DE locale, the letter "ü" (0xfc) shouldn't end up after "z" (0x7a) / at the end of the list, as it would with a `strcmp()` sorting, but be sorted equivalent to "ue" (0x75 0x65)...

And because you can't probably know all facts about all existing locales, the standard library provides `strcoll()`, `strxfrm()`, `wcscoll()`, `wcsxfrm()` and the `LC_COLLATE` option to `setlocale()`, which do the locale-specific stuff for you.

Welcome to the world of internationalization. ;-) Lucky the question explicitly asks for "ASCII collating", which means you get away with `strcmp()`...

Answer (score 0):

I think it means to simple sort the string you read, and sort them depending on the characters ASCII values.

So if you input two strings: `"aa"` and `"aA"`, the order after sorting should be `"aA"` and `"aa"`. This order is because the ASCII value for `'a'` is higher than the ASCII value for `'A'`.

Comment: So do I just sum the character constants in the string and then sort the strings based on this sum score ?

Comment: I think I will have to use `strcmp` string function, which does this lexicographical comparison ..........

Answer (score 0):

Collation means a defined ordering, the task is to sort the input strings in ASCII order, i.e. as a standard "sort" command, and not change the ordering of the characters in each string -- the wording could be clearer, you can only infer the intent based on the other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:

> ascii collating sequence
>   Web definitions
>   The sequence in which the characters are defined in the ASCII chart. (See Appendix B.).

So you should order the strings by the values of their character codes / char elements.